# react-native-debugger disconnecting and showing error when In-App Developer Menu is opened

Tags: react-native, react-devtools, react-native-debugger

I have recently upgraded my react native to the latest version 0.62.1 and also downloaded the required react-native-debugger app (standalone app version 0.11.1 ) as specified in the react-native-debugger doc. Now when i enable remote js debugging everything works fine until i press cmd + d for ios or cmd + m for android to open in app developer menu after that debugger is disconnecting automatically and showing the error as shown in the below image.

[link to react-native-debugger error image when in app developer menu is opened](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bBsYb.jpg)

As shown in the above image it says Bridge was already shutdown. Because of this i am unable to do inspect element inside react-native-debugger. I have searched in the internet regarding this specific error but unfortunately i did't find any solution.

**Edit 1**

I have set up a new react native project with react-native-cli and tested. It is also giving the same error. I don't know whether the problem is with new react native version 0.62 or react-devtools version 4.

Comment: react native debugger app doesn't works well, I have also switched to chrome debugging.

Comment: looks like an issue has been opened regarding this in react-native-debugger repo here is the link https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger/issues/494

Comment: @TusharPandey How can U inspect elements in Chrome?

Answer (score 0):

This error appears to go away in `react-native@0.66.0`, but I experienced it on `0.64.2`. The workaround I found was to open inspector without using the dev menu. Two ways:

1. `cmd` + `i`
2. Right-click inside `react-native-debugger` and select "Toggle Element Inspector"

[image]

If you do open dev menu and break connection again, simply reload to reset the state.

You might also need to confirm your app's `react-devtools-core` version from your `node_modules` or `lock` files match the version embedded inside `react-native-debugger`. I documented all this here:

https://gist.github.com/sschottler/7771dc034d38b89d9d587dc5d358c386